# error running rails -server, receiving error: yarn: error: no such option: --integrity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg

I am working in Rails 6.0.3.4 and Ruby 2.7.1 and when I run `rails -s`, I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: --integrity


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please change `check_yarn_integrity`
to `false` in your webpacker config file (config/webpacker.yml).
```

When I run `yarn install --check-files`, I receive the following error:

```
yarn: error: no such option: --check-files
```

And I do have check_yarn_integrity set to false in webpacker.yml.

Comment: Your yarn installation is probably out of date. How did you install npm and yarn in the first place? What operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `npm install --global yarn`

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed install `yarn` using `npm`, but you should do it inside Docker.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg2 && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g yarn

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --check-files
```

Here is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg2 && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g yarn

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --check-files

# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to the container
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Install dependencies
RUN bundle install

# Copy the rest of the application to the container
COPY . .

# Set up environment variables
ENV DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@db:5432/app_development

# Start the Rails server
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Then run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. It should work.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. Using docker is unrelated to the problem.